# Error when running powershell command remotely

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to run Powershell command on remote machine. This is method that I am using (localhost:131 is because I use tunnel to remote machine's port 5985):

```
  public string RunRemotePowerShellCommand(string command)
    {
           System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char c in _password.ToCharArray())
            {
                password.AppendChar(c);
            }

            string schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Powershell";

            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false,
                "localhost", 131, "/wsman", schema, new PSCredential(_domain + @"\" + _userName, password));

            using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
            {
                remoteRunspace.Open();
                using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;
                    powershell.AddCommand(command);
                    powershell.Invoke();

                    Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

                    // convert the script result into a single string
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                    }
                    return stringBuilder.ToString();
                }
            }
    }
```

I'm trying to run following command:

```
D:\FolderName\scriptName.ps1 -action editbinding -component "comp1","comp2","comp3","comp4"
```

Like this:

```
RunRemotePowerShellCommand(@"D:\FolderName\scriptName.ps1 -action editbinding -component ""comp1"",""comp2"",""comp3"",""comp4""");
```

but I get:

```
Error: System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: The term 'D:\FolderName\scriptName.ps1 -action editbinding -component "comp1","comp2","comp3","comp4"' is not recognized as a name of cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if the path is included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

The method works fine with simple commands, and the command that I want to run is ok when I run it on remote machine.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
 Dusan

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `powershell.AddParameter()` method to add the parameters for your command.  The AddCommand() call should name just the command: cmdlet name, function name, path to script, etc. From the docs:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-Process");
ps.AddArgument("wmi*");
ps.AddCommand("Sort-Object");
ps.AddParameter("descending");
ps.AddArgument("id");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this and got Error: "Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it." I tried few more things and problem seems to be with path to the remote script (altough it is correct).

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar requirement.

My solution was to create a powershell function in C# code and use it over the powershell remote session like.

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace PowerShellTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string func = @"function Test { Write-Host 'hello' };";
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript(func);
            ps.Invoke();
            ps.AddCommand("Test");
            ps.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully executed function");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```